# Deadly Diamond of Death

Tags: meaning, british-english, slang

What does actually means by "Deadly Diamond of Dead". Although i find it in a programming language but i am concerned about it's literal meaning. Is it some slang?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't it supposed to be "[Deadly Diamond of death](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond_problem#The_diamond_problem)"?

As you mentioned, you understood what it means when it refers to what it's supposed to mean.

Deadly features of dead - refers to the features of dead (may be person or anything, depending on context) that are deadly.

Deadly diamond of dead - refers to the diamond of dead (may be a person or anything depending on context) that are deadly.

Well, "deadly diamond of death" is a name of "multiple inheritance issue" in OOP, or may be in all languages where class is supported. Anyways, I am not into computer programming anymore and hence I forgot all, can't be more specific about it. But my point is, it's a name and like all name we shouldn't seek the literal meaning for they might not lead to the concept or something/someone they refers to.

Say for example, in India Puja is a very common name of a female, but the literal meaning of "puja" is worship of god.

Comment: @ Man_from_India: I like the example. It reminds me of someone special. :)

Comment: @Mr.Pandey This is a public place, and so please keep your special in your special ;)

Comment: @ Man_from_India: Sorry about that although it was just jokes apart.

Comment: @Mr.Pandey No need of sorry. It was just a casual aside ;)